# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] How can I match it against all possibilities of a single domain?

Tags: php, http

This is probably quite hard to explain, so I'll try to make it as simple as possible:

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

switch($ref) {
    case "http://www.facebook.com":
    $ref_name = "Facebook";
    break;
    case "http://www.twitter.com":
    $ref_name = "Twitter";
    break;
}

?>
```

From what I know, `HTTP_REFERER` pulls the entire referrer url (e.g. `www.facebook.com/abc/xyz/mno=prq`) as oppose to the top-level domain. I'd like to be able to match `$ref` against something so that all referrer's whether from say `http://static.facebook.com` (a sub-domain) or `http://www.facebook.com/profile_id/bla` (a url with additional folders and parameters after the top-level domain) are given the value of `"http://www.facebook.com"`.

What's the most simple and effective way to do so?

Any comments/answers etc will be greatly appreciated :)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php)

```
$ref = 'http://static.facebook.com';

$host = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($ref, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
switch ($host) {
    case 'facebook.com':
        break;

    case 'twitter.com':
        break;
}
```

**Update**: Have a look at [Root Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/) if you're dealing with *special* TLDs.

Comment: This is a good first step but doesn't solve the problem yet. What about `static.facebook.com` or `facebook.com`? And if you want to add another complexity, consider the (fictional) `facebook.co.uk` where a simple extraction process would yield `.co` :)

Comment: Thanks Yoshi! @Pekka, would it be possible to draw some form of wildcard on `static.` `www.` etc?

Comment: Ok, it will not work for tlds like `co.uk`. I guess one would have to use a list of tlds to get this to work 100%.

Comment: You've been a huge help man! I'm not really looking for any tld's aside from `.com` but thanks for the suggestion :)!!